# Line element from react-native-svg not working on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I am trying to use Line element from react-native-svg however it does not appear when I use iOS but does appear on Android operating systems. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance

Comment: Whoever upvoted this, please review the description of the upvoting privilege. I think you are abusing it. Please understand that upvoting an information-scarce question like this sheds an unfavorable light on this post and its author. It risks getting this inexperienced new user into undeserved trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `Line` element is wrapped in [`<Svg>`](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg#svg) with `width` and `height` defined.

Comment: @Yunnosch thank you for your well deserved answer almighty one.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, but this is not my answer. Praise should go to the author.

Comment: Yes you're correct @Yunnosch, asking for details is definitely one for comments, my bad!